# Bootstrap Dropdown in Table Detail

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

What is the right way to add a dropdown? I'm passing this info to a JS/PHP and everything else is working... I am hoping to change as little as possible!

```
    <table id="create">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>End</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input style="min-width: 180px" class="form-control name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contest Name"></td>
        <td> BOOTSTRAP DROPDOWN </td>
        <td><input class="form-control start" type="date" name="start" placeholder="Start Date (mm/dd/yyyy)"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control end" type="date" name="end" placeholder="End Date (mm/dd/yyyy)"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control active" type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" CHECKED></td>
        <td><input class="btn btn-success create" type="button" name="create" value="Create"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something this is pretty straight forward [since the documentation is found here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls). Just scroll down to the `select` section to read about it. Add this code in your form.

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I must have done something wrong the first time I tried this! Thanks. I'll see what I can do with the JS/PHP sides.